# Whats the distiction between import/require and reference tags in Typescript

Tags: unit-testing, typescript

I am trying to test some front end Typescript code with Mocha. The problem is that, I am using Typescript reference tags for intellisense in Webstorm to resolve my front end code. I have to load the files in the browser using requireJS, because reference tags don't do that. This far, I am able to get.

But then, I want to test the code with Mocha - which is where the problem begins. Mocha test files do not seem to relate with the code being tested unless its imported using import/require statements, even though Typescript reference tags have been added. If, I try to export the code in the ts file being tested, and import it in Mocha Unit Test files, then other ts files containing the front end code can't resolve it anymore.

Consider this situation:

```
TS File A references TS File B using Typescript reference tags.
Mocha Unit Test X tries to reference TS file B using reference tags, which does not work.
Mocha Unit Test X tries to reference TS file B using import/require statments, which requires that code in TS file B be "exported".
If TS file B is "exported" then File A can't reference it anymore.
```

I am sort of trapped in the ridiculous dependency management system thats coming up, because of me trying to test a Typescript/NodeJS project with Mocha. Please help me understand how dependencies work here and how can I a get this sorted out/simplified.

If there is a better and equally powerful framework suited for this sort of project that can provide Unit testing (and end to end testing), PLEASE suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest solution : Use AMD on the front end (not reference merging) and CommonJS on mocha. The obvious disadvantage is that you need to compile your code twice, Once when running frontend, and seperately when running mocha. The JS generated in mocha case will be different from the JS generated in frontend case. You might want to use `--outDir` to seperate the two cases.

Comment: Thanks, though I'm clear on whats the difference between reference tags and import/require statements.

Comment: I am already using RequireJS on the front end to load js files. What further do you mean by AMD?

Comment: if you are using AMD you should not need / use reference tags to avoid confusing the compiler (the compiler thinking something is available when it is not) See TypeScript module patterns : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0&hd=1

Comment: In that case what are reference tags good for in Typescript? From your video (Which is very nice by the way!), it appears the only use of reference tags is when you want to keep your typescript code modularized in multiple files, and compile them to a single js file for testing or production - using the --out flag - and then use the js file as a single external module. Is that right?

Comment: @EternallyCurious for your code that is mostly correct + you can use reference tags to include definitions for javascript code which you still `require`